# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when switching back and forth between tableviews

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, nsobject

A brief over view of what I am trying to do.

I am using the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method inside my UITableViewController subclass which is catching a row selection from that view like so...

```
//..... inside tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        //--- Get the subview ready for use
        VehicleSearchResponseTableViewController *vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController = [[VehicleSearchResponseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VehicleSearchResponseTableViewController" bundle:nil];
        // ...
        //--- Sets the back button for the new view that loads
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController animated:YES];

        if(indexPath.row == 0) {
            vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController.title = @"Mans";

            EngineRequests *engineRequest = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
            [engineRequest getMans]; 
            [engineRequest release]; 
        }
        if(indexPath.row == 1) {
//.... etc etc
```

As you can see in this method I set up a few things, pushing the new view onto the viewstack and changing the back buttons text, then I go into catching the different rows and then initiating a method in a subclass of nsobject where I want to have all my connection/request stuff going on.

Inside my NSObject I have several different methods for the different cells that you can select on the UITableViewController, basicly they specify different strings that will then initialize my ASIHTTPRequest wrapper to make a connection to the php script and catch all the data that will come back from the database.. NSObject looks like this.

```
//.... NSObject.m
- (IBAction) getMans
{
    NSString *mansString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"mans.php"];
    [self grabURLInBackground:mansString];
    [manusString release];
}
//....cont....
//--- Connect to server and send request ---------------->>
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(NSString *)setUrlString
{
    NSString *startURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/CodeTest/%@", setUrlString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:startURL];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; //Pass request text from server over to NSString 
    NSData *responseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //Create NSData object for Parser Delegate and load with responseString
    NSLog(@"stuff %@",responseData);

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

From here I would like to pass the data I am getting from the requestFinished method back over to the newly pushed UITableView.. However I have an error before I am able to get this far that I need to solve... if I run the simulator and click back and forth between the views (the main UITableViewController with the cells and then the newly popped view where I want to put the data) the application falls over and pops up an error in **main.m** Thread 1: program receive signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. I just don;t know whats causing because from what I can tell my code is not so bad.

Also when I debug my application I notice that once grabURLInBackground method has finished it bounces out back to the getMans method then goes back over to the UITableViewController and continues through the if statements, completely neglecting the requestFinished and requestFailed methods, and I just cannot figure out why.

I guess I am not sure if I am calling the methods and functions I need to use in the right places so if you have any suggestions or answers on how I can improve or if you know where my error is coming form that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with the code above but I'd guess that your bad access exception is due to the handling of your EngineRequests and use of AsiHttpRequest.

The code here

```
EngineRequests *engineRequest = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
[engineRequest getMans]; 
[engineRequest release];
```

effectively creates an object then deallocates as soon as getMans has finished running.

Then inside the engineRequest object **this code**

```
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

requests that AsiHttpRequest **notify the almost certainly released object** once the request has completed.

There may be other issues at work here but I'd start by restructuring to try to keep this object around until at least after it's received the response from AsiHttpRequest.

Comment: you need a way to make sure the engineRequest hangs around until at least after the http request is finished.  I'd probably create the engineRequest in the view which gets pulled and keep it as an object variable then release it once the request comes back. Autorelease will probably only make things harder to debug in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I think I am going to put this EngineRequests into my new UItableview and change it depending on the title of the view that I am setting from the parent that way I can use the one view for multiple different result sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the brief overview, but generally when you bad_access and end up in the main application method, it's usually because you autoreleased something, then released it, and it craps out when the autorelease pool is drained.  Might want to turn on NSZombiesEnabled and look for memory problems.

Comment: just a quick note to agree that using Instruments or the NSZombiesEnabled stuff to look for zombies would also be a great way to start debugging this sort of thing!

Comment: ah, right I will look into this, I have been using Product>Analyze and seen a couple potential memory leaks that I have fixed.. but will look for this zombie thing.

Answer (score 0):

Who does receive your request?

The sender (and receiver) object is engineRequest. 
But you release Engine Request in that very moment after you issued the async request (by mens of the getMans Method.

I would suggest that you 
1. move the code

```
    vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController.title = @"Mans";

    EngineRequests *engineRequest = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
    [engineRequest getMans]; 
    [engineRequest release];
```

from your `UITableViewController's` didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to your `vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method. 
2. to retain your `EngineRequests` object and keep it in some instance variable within `vehicleSearchResponseTableViewController`and do not release it before the request is completely processed, either successfully or in error.

Comment: I know what you mean.. However the data in that table can change deepening on which cell is selected in the parent view. I am trying to load different data depending on which cell is selected into one UITableViewController.

Comment: Yes, but by releasing the engineRequest object before the http request is finished you will in the best case never receive the data and in the worst case you risk bad access aborts.